# How to select the column name of a column whose values are updated in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

let's say there is a table having few columns whose rows are filled with values. If some values are updated in a particular column of that table using update query, how to select that specific column name whose values are updated in postgresql?

Comment: you question is not clear , what is the problem you are trying to solve? provide sample data and desired output

Answer (score 0):

This question appears to ask for a *way* to check validity that any data was actually updated by a script.

This is a general template that might be usable -

1. Before `UPDATE`

```
SELECT t1.col1,
       t1.col2,
       t1.col3
 FROM table1 t1
```

2. Code to `UPDATE`

```
UPDATE table1 t1
SET t1.col1 = 'Some Value',
    t1.col2 = 'Some Value',
    t1.col3 = 'Some Value'
 WHERE t1.id = 'Unique ID'
```

3. Verify `UPDATE`

```
SELECT t1.col1,
       t1.col2,
       t1.col3
 FROM table1 t1
```

All can be run at the same time so the Before/After can be seen from steps 1 and 3.

Comment: I mean name of the column has to be appeared in separate column whose values were updated. How do you do that using information_schema.columns or something?